# CSS: Horizontally centering text between two arrows

Tags: html, css

I am working on a HTML/CSS project. I have the following code:

category-arrows.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CSS Arrows</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="category-arrows.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="arrows-container">
            <div class="up-arrow"></div>
            <div class="category-rank">
                <p>2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="down-arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

category-arrows.css:

```
.up-arrow {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 15px solid #000000;
    border-right: 15px solid #000000;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 15%;
}

.up-arrow:hover, .down-arrow:hover {
    border-top: 15px solid #28bfa6;
    border-right: 15px solid #28bfa6;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.down-arrow {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 15px solid #000000;
    border-right: 15px solid #000000;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 15%;
    position: relative;
    top: -105px;
}

.category-rank {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: -69px; 
    margin-top: -36px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

The result of the above code is the following:

[image]

When the number between the arrows is -1, I get the following:

[image]

When the number between the arrows is negative (e.g. -1), the text is not fully horizontally centred between the arrows. I am using the CSS `right` property to centre the text between the arrows. This works fine when the number between the arrows does not have a negative sign in front of it.

I would like the text between the arrows to always be horizontally centred. However, I am not sure what the best way to do this is. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to check if `number < 0`, and then use `str.substring(1)` to remove the first character of that number (the minus sign), and then display a minus sign next to it in fixed position in a span for example or whatever.

That way the number would always be centered, and if negative that minus sign would show itself and not move the number itself.

Comment: One is this the way Julien has said another way around is to show plus next the positive number (that way both will have signs). So actually the whole thing is centered because sign is a part of it in the first place but anyhow that's how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is all broken if you'd just add borders and some padding you'll see everything is miss aligned.

```css
body * {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.up-arrow {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 15px solid #000000;
  border-right: 15px solid #000000;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius: 15%;
}

.up-arrow:hover,
.down-arrow:hover {
  border-top: 15px solid #28bfa6;
  border-right: 15px solid #28bfa6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.down-arrow {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 15px solid #000000;
  border-right: 15px solid #000000;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius: 15%;
  position: relative;
  top: -105px;
}

.category-rank {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: -69px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows-container">
  <div class="up-arrow"></div>
  <div class="category-rank">
    <p>-1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="down-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

---

You should instead relay on the changing element, the `p` is the one that changes so we align the arrows according to it.

`display:inline-flex` to the container will make it shrink to fit the widest element which the p tag, and we apply `align-items: center;` to center horizontally the arrows.

```css
/* remove unnecessary padding and margin */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrows-container {
  padding: 20px; /* just to be safe */
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.up-arrow {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 15px solid #000000;
  border-right: 15px solid #000000;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 15%;
}

.up-arrow:hover,
.down-arrow:hover {
  border-top: 15px solid #28bfa6;
  border-right: 15px solid #28bfa6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.down-arrow {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 15px solid #000000;
  border-right: 15px solid #000000;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  border-radius: 15%;
}

.category-rank {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}


/* For the red line to show center, Not needed */

.arrows-container {
  position: relative;
}

.arrows-container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows-container">
  <div class="up-arrow"></div>
  <div class="category-rank">
    <p>-1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="down-arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="arrows-container">
  <div class="up-arrow"></div>
  <div class="category-rank">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="down-arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="arrows-container">
  <div class="up-arrow"></div>
  <div class="category-rank">
    <p>58</p>
  </div>
  <div class="down-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

I tried cleaning the code  a little bit.